# Filter One year date dynamically each time - VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have to filter one year data each time I run the macro . But I defined the variables for date range . but unable to put >= and <= values with variable in filter criteria.

```
Sub OneYear()
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Cells.Select
Range("E1").Activate
Selection.AutoFilter

Dim FrmTime As Date
FrmTime = Now() - 365

Dim ToTime As Date
ToTime = Now()

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AJ$2621").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=ToTime, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=FrmTime

Range("A1").Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your search in quotes:

```
criteria1: = "<= " & ToTime
```

Do this for each of your variables.

Also try using the macro record button then manually do what you want.  It would have given you the clues needed to find the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you !! This what I need